# iOS - Access Modal's Parent Property

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I am probably overcomplicating this but is there a way to access a property of a modal's parent?

So, I call "presentModalViewController" and then I can access some properties on the view controller that just called it from the modal.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: In my experience, I always use delegation pattern to get/set parentView property for the view that currently present modal.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using iOS 5, you can call self.presentingViewController to access the parent view controller

here is [apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Comment: I am letting this app support older iOS versions, so I couldn't do this.
Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was nearly correct - you want `presentingViewController` rather than `parentViewController`, however this could lead to tight coupling (dependency between the two classes, meaning they can only work with each other) if you're not careful.

It's best to define a protocol still, but your delegate property is not necessary - it will have the same value as the `presentingViewController` property.

Comment: presentingViewController is iOS5 only, and this needs to be compatible with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so since asking this question I have tried a few techniques which looked as though they would work but didn't.

Such an example is this.

```
((pController *)self.parentViewController).testString;
```

However, while it was a regular UIViewController that presented the modal, the parent was actually a UITabBarController, and even using selectedViewController didn't work.

My solution was to add to my modal's .h file

```
id delegate;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

After synthesizing it in the implementation file, alloc/init the modalViewController, but just before presenting it I set

```
modalViewController.delegate = self;
```

This way I could call self.delegate from within my modal. This still wasn't enough as this doesn't say which view controller it is, so I can't say

```
self.delegate.testString;
```

But the casting I learnt earlier allowed me to get a fully working solution of

```
((pController *)self.delegate).testString;
```

I hope I haven't just babbled my way through this, and I hope that this can help someone in the future.

Comment: The proper way would be define a protocol, and define the delegate as id<protocol> delegate. then at the accessing point, you can just call  self.delegate.testString rather than hard casting.